# jQuery selector for data-filter

Tags: jquery

Having a link with 
    data-filter="*" 
I fail to trigger the clicking of the link by

```
jQuery("a [data-filter='*']").trigger("click");
```

How can this be done correctly?

https://jsfiddle.net/yefjsmwf/

Comment: Spaces in a selector denote child selectors.  If you want a logical AND conditional, remove the space.

Comment: All your issues are typo related. Spaces in the wrong spots as Taplar noted, and incorrect function syntax. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ndLvs2yd/. Your question should also include a [mcve]. Don't ask us to visit a third-party site for a complete example when there's no reason for you not to post it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Changed your js code :

```js
jQuery("a[data-filter='*']").click(function() {
 jQuery("#other").css("color", "green");
});

jQuery("a[data-filter='*']").trigger("click");
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-filter="*">Past and Upcoming Events</a>
<a href="#" data-filter="Past">Past Events</a>
<a id="other" href="#">some other link</a>
```

Hope, this works for you.